# Instantiate Storyboard from local Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I try to instatiat a ViewController vom a local SPM Package but I always get the error "Could not find a storyboard".

```
let myViewController = UIStoryboard(
      name: "MyStoryboard",
      bundle: Bundle(
              url: Bundle.main.url(
                   forResource: "myModule_myModule",
                   withExtension: "bundle"
              )!
      )
).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController")
```

This code works when using it as an remote package, but not when dragging it to Xcode and use it local.

Thanks Bernhard

Comment: Did you add your package under `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content?`

Comment: Oh nooo, that was the problem. Why is it added for remote packages and not local. Thanks @NoeOnJupiter you saved my day.

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter Would you like to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `Remote Packages`, When adding a `Local` one `Xcode` doesn't prompt you to add it to a `target`. Hence you need to add it manually in your `Target's General settings`, under `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`